# Full width button only on xs screens

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using [Material UI](https://mui.com/) and I'm creating a form, I have a <[Button](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-button/#main-content)> component inside that form [Grid](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid/).

I want the button to take its regular width and height on **md**  screens and above, but want to have it full width and a bit of extra **padding-y** on **xs** screens. But I'm not able to figure out how?

Full code: [**or view in codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/white-mountain-qw8czj?file=/src/App.js)

```
import "./styles.css";
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Grid container spacing={2}>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <Button variant="contained">Submit</Button>
      </Grid>
{/* 
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <Button fullWidth variant="contained">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Grid>
 */}
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

Comment: You can use `sx` prop and style the button accordingly based on the screen width. Your updated [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-bash-kuot5f?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: You can find more details about the [sx](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/#the-sx-prop) prop and how you can use the [breakpoints](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/30152) in the sx prop.

Comment: Apart from sx prop, you can also use the [grid breakpoints](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid/#grid-with-multiple-breakpoints) to manage the width of the button on different screen widths. But for responsive padding, you have to use the custom css i.e. sx prop.

Comment: @JunaidFaryad, thanks. `theme.breakpoints.down("576")` why `576`? is it because the default theme predefined breakpoint is 576? what if I was changing that breakpoint somewhere in my application programmatically? how can I detect that? for instance, is there something to say `theme.breakpoints.down(theme.breakpoints.xs)`?

Comment: Yes, you should use the theme's predefined or custom breakpoints for responsiveness. That 576 was just for demonstration of the functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using the `useMediaQuery`[[1]](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-use-media-query/#main-content) MUI hook as follows:

Full code: (*sorry for not providing a **code sandbox**, but useMediaQuery doesn't work with the **code sandbox** for some reason*)

```
import "./styles.css";
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import useMediaQuery from "@mui/material/useMediaQuery";

export default function App() {
  const isFullWidth = useMediaQuery((theme) => theme.breakpoints.only("sm"));
  return (
    <Grid container spacing={2}>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <Button fullWidth={isFullWidth} variant="contained">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

I don't know why all that was actually required, we should have some syntax as follows:

```
// this is not real, but just an example
<Button fullWidth={(theme) => theme.breakpoints.is("sm")} variant="contained">
```

anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the width as follows:

```
<Button variant="contained" sx={{ width: { xs: "100%", md: "auto" } }}>
  Submit
</Button>
```

Hope this helps!